# Add an icon before the input element in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to add an icon in front of the input element of react select. I am able to get the icon in placeholder but the problem with a placeholder is that when I select some data from the dropdown the placeholder icon gets removed. I need some help to get the icon in front of the Select statement.

Here's the code of what I have achieved till now

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select, { components } from 'react-select'

export default class InfluencersForm extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.handleInfluencerName = this.handleInfluencerName.bind(this);
    }
    handleInfluencerName(event){
        console.log(event)
    }
    render() {
        const influencers = [
            { value: 'abc', label: 'abc' },
            { value: 'def', label: 'def' }
        ]

        const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
            return components.DropdownIndicator && (
                <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
                    <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style={{ position: 'initial' }}></i>
                </components.DropdownIndicator>
            );
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Select
                        options={influencers}
                        isMulti={false}
                        onChange={this.handleInfluencerName}
                        isSearchable={true}
                        components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
                        placeholder={placeholderComponent}
                        classNamePrefix="vyrill"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const placeholderComponent = (
    <div>
        <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style={{ position: 'initial' }}></i>
        I am placeholder
    </div>
);
```

Comment: You need to provide code

Comment: @robinsax the answer is updated with code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but possibly you need to use `:before` styling to do it?

Comment: but I was looking for something in which I could use my readymade case classes like font awesome classes or something.

Comment: You can add new div with icon at left instead, place holder will be hidden once you have value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on what you've already done I would do a combination of custom style + custom component.

```
export default class InfluencersForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleInfluencerName = this.handleInfluencerName.bind(this);
  }
  handleInfluencerName(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
  render() {
    const influencers = [
      { value: "abc", label: "abc" },
      { value: "def", label: "def" }
    ];

    const ValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
      return (
        components.ValueContainer && (
          <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
            {!!children && (
              <i
                className="fa fa-search"
                aria-hidden="true"
                style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 6 }}
              />
            )}
            {children}
          </components.ValueContainer>
        )
      );
    };

    const DropdownIndicator = props => {
      return (
        components.DropdownIndicator && (
          <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
            <i
              className="fa fa-search"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          </components.DropdownIndicator>
        )
      );
    };

    const styles = {
      valueContainer: base => ({
        ...base,
        paddingLeft: 24
      })
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Select
            options={influencers}
            isMulti={false}
            onChange={this.handleInfluencerName}
            isSearchable={true}
            components={{ DropdownIndicator, ValueContainer }}
            classNamePrefix="vyrill"
            styles={styles}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my custom style I have added an arbitrary `paddingLeft` of `24` to make some space and add the desired icon. You might have to change it depending of the icon you want to use.

Then in `ValueContainer` next to the `children` I have put the fontAwesome icon.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qny24wkzq) of my solution.

Comment: The live example doesn't work. If I select "abc", the "abc" overlaps with magnifying glass.

Comment: @Melissa the live example wasn't up to date now it is