# Delete dynamically added items [react-select]

Tags: react-select

I'm using the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) control. The items displayed in the dropdown list are a combination of fixed items plus dynamically added items.

I'd like to be able to delete the dynamically generated items directly in the dropdown panel by adding an icon next to the label. When clicked this should remove the item.

I know the code to add/remove items programmatically. It's just a case of updating state. The thing I'm stuck on is how to add UI to the react-select dropdown panel and fire a click event when it's clicked on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an icon before the input element in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928958/add-an-icon-before-the-input-element-in-react-select)

Comment: I'm specifically looking to customize the dropdown items rather than the input element.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components) you can [replace](https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components) the option component in `react-select`.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const CustomOption = ({ innerProps }) =>
    <div {...innerProps}>{/* your component internals */}</div>

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Select components={{ Option: CustomOption }} />;
  }
}
```

That way you could add an icon `<span onClick={() => this.deleteOption(optionId)}>&times;</span>` to the CustomOption component and use css `position: absolute` etc. to get it where you want and style it, preferably through a `className`

Comment: @dgwyer That is the rough idea. Tell me if you get stuck with the details, I'll be happy to assist.