# How to add an icon to the left side in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-select, storybook

Attempt to add the icon to the left side in `react-select`, but default props of `react-select` can't do it

that is what i need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p4X9.jpg)

```
import Select, {
  ClearIndicatorProps,
  components,
  DropdownIndicatorProps
} from "react-select";
import Icon from "@greenatom/icons";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "../data";
import { COLORS } from "../Pallette/Colors";
import { CustomSelect, IconWrap } from "./style";
import { IProps } from "./types";
import {IconWrapper} from "src/components/Button/style";

const TSelect = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const DropdownIndicator = (
  props: DropdownIndicatorProps<ColourOption, true>
) => (
  <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
    <Icon
      nameOfIcon="broken-arrow-down-2"
      width={20}
      height={20}
      fill={COLORS.darkgrayscale1}
    />
  </components.DropdownIndicator>
);

const ClearIndicator = (props: ClearIndicatorProps<ColourOption, true>) => (
  <components.ClearIndicator {...props}>
    <Icon nameOfIcon="broken-close-circle" width={16} height={16} />
  </components.ClearIndicator>
);

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, IProps>(
  (
    {
      children,
      icon,
      viewType = "primary",
      isPressed,
      isDisabled,
      className,
      onClick,
      ...props
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
      onClick && !isDisabled && onClick(event);
    };
    return (
      <CustomSelect
        classNamePrefix="Select"
        options={TSelect}
        isClearable
        components={{ DropdownIndicator, ClearIndicator }}
        defaultInputValue={"P2-l"}
        {icon && <IconWrap>{icon}</IconWrap>}
      />
    );
  }
);

Button.displayName = "Button";

export default Button;
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an icon before the input element in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928958/add-an-icon-before-the-input-element-in-react-select)